# Who/what made the noises on Miss Lucy's window?

Tags: dracula, bram-stoker

I'm reading Bram Stoker's Dracula, and there are several passages where Miss Lucy is extremely ill, and resting in bed. During these occasions, there is very often a noise at the window, like something hitting it. The characters think that must be made by a big bat. I don't have the book in front of me right now, but IIRC these noises even occur on the nights Dr. Van Helsing and Dr. Seward are taking care of her.

Question: **Is the noise begin caused by Dracula? If so, is he so dumb as to be struggling with a closed window, even when there are protectors nears his victims?**

I  am not through the whole book yet, but given its structure I don't think this issue is going to be explained.

Comment: Hi.  I've edited your question to fix up some of the sentence structure and word choice.  If I changed the meaning by mistake, feel free to roll the edits back.

Comment: @AdeleC thanks, I'am not a native and commit grotesque errors sometimes

Comment: Its only grotesque if no one can make sense of it.  You did fine.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe we are ever told explicitly. But it is indeed hinted to be Dracula struggling with the locked window, since later on we are told by Van Helsing that Dracula can turn into a bat among other things.

Comment: Yeah, I concluded it was him in the form of a bat also.